# Зависимости в maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, зависимости

Проект состоит из 3 репозиториев server, outerConnecter, core. как в класса в server использовать
классы из core и outerConnecter?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>core.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.26</slf4j.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ....
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>${java.version}</source>
                  <target>${java.version}</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Server pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>core.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

outerConnecter pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>outerConnecter</groupId>
  <artifactId>outerConnecter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>core.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>${java.version}</source>
                  <target>${java.version}</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Я не могу использовать 1 общий родительский pom, т.к. server pom.xml должен наследоваться от spring boot pom.

Comment: Ну наверное нужно добавить зависимость outerConnector в server pom.xml, нет?

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ. Это очевидно, просто я не знал как правильно это сделать, прикрепляю видео с туториалом как это сделать правильно по шагам https://youtu.be/5Nnbgqr1P04?si=4oQvP0DYDg0MqRCp